# ggplot legend for colour with auxiliary variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to create a plot with a quadratic curve in black, and horizontal lines at various levels in different colours, with a legend (guide) that labels the horizontal line colours.  I can't quite figure it out -- I've tried a couple of variations that seem to make sense to me, but I can't seem to force the legend to appear.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw()) ## cosmetic
hdat <- data.frame(harvest_rate=c(5,15,25,30))
r <- 1; K <- 100
ggplot(hdat)+
    geom_hline(data=hdat,aes(yintercept=harvest_rate,
               colour=factor(harvest_rate)))+
    stat_function(fun=function(x) r*x*(1-x/K),colour="black")+
    expand_limits(x=c(0,110))
```

[image]

The lines come out OK, but the legend/guide is not there.

If I do this instead:

```
ggplot(hdat,aes(yintercept=harvest_rate,
               colour=factor(harvest_rate)))+
    geom_hline()+
    stat_function(fun=function(x) r*x*(1-x/K),colour="black")+
    expand_limits(x=c(0,110))
```

then to my surprise the horizontal lines don't get drawn at all!

I've also tried (I started this way) setting up a data frame with `x` and `y` variables,

```
 d <- data.frame(x=0:110)
 d <- transform(d,y=r*x*(1-x/K))
 ggplot(d,aes(x,y))+geom_line()+
      geom_hline(data=hdat,aes(yintercept=harvest_rate,
               colour=factor(harvest_rate)))+
      scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

The guide doesn't show up that way either.

If I  set `colour=NA` in the initial `ggplot` call the legend appears, but the curve disappears.  If I set `colour=factor(1)` as follows

```
 ggplot(d,aes(x,y,colour=factor(1)))+geom_line()+
      geom_hline(data=hdat,aes(yintercept=harvest_rate,
               colour=factor(harvest_rate)))+
      scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

I get a curve and a legend, but the curve is in a bogus colour.  If I override by setting `geom_line(colour="black")` then the legend disappears again ...

I would be very grateful for (1) a hack that works and (2) an explanation of the logic that I'm missing!

Comment: try `show_guide=TRUE` in your geom_hline layer (presumably often used as an annotation, therefore not included in the legend)

Comment: OK, documentation-reading fail ... feel free to write that up as an answer!

Comment: @baptiste If you want to claim the answer, i will delete mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete answer:

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw()) ## cosmetic
hdat <- data.frame(harvest_rate=c(5,15,25,30))
r <- 1; K <- 100

ggplot(hdat)+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=harvest_rate, colour=factor(harvest_rate)), show_guide=TRUE)+
  stat_function(fun=function(x) r*x*(1-x/K),colour="black")+
  expand_limits(x=c(0,110)) +
  labs(colour = "Harvest rate") # making a pretty legend title
```

The result:

[image]